# Aggregating results from nested tuples based on conditions

Tags: python, tuples

i have a nested tuple and i want to get a table with results, i'm trying to use comprehension on this but i'm not getting the best results.

```
team = ((35, 'Team1'),(8, 'Team2'),(55, 'Team1'),(65, 'Team2'),(90, 'Team1'))
```

output example:

```
       first  second totalgoals
team1    1      2        3
team2    1      1        2
```

Can anyone give me some help?

Comment: How are your getting from you input to output? I don't see those numbers in your original tuples.

Comment: What are the first and second column here?

Comment: It's like a football match. First half (1 - 45th minute), second half (46th - 90th minute)

Comment: Please decribe how you want the table be converted from the tuples. What does mean the first number in the tuple?

Comment: Did one of the below solutions help? Feel free to accept one (tick on left), or ask for clarification.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
team = ((35, 'Team1'),(8, 'Team2'),(55, 'Team1'),(65, 'Team2'),(90, 'Team1'))
results = {a:[sum(c < 45 and d == a for c, d in team), sum(c >= 45 and d == a for c, d in team)] for a in set(d for _, d in team)} 
print('\tfirst  second totalgoals')
for a, [first, second] in results.items():
  print(f'{a}\t{first}\t{second}\t{first+second}')
```

Output:

```
    first  second totalgoals
Team1   1   2   3
Team2   1   1   2
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a pure Python dictionary-based solution:

```
from operator import itemgetter

lst = ((35, 'Team1'),(8, 'Team2'),(55, 'Team1'),(65, 'Team2'),(90, 'Team1'))

teams = map(itemgetter(1), lst)
d = {team: dict.fromkeys(('first', 'second', 'total'), 0) for team in teams}

for minutes, team in lst:
    if minutes <= 45:
        d[team]['first'] += 1
    else:
        d[team]['second'] += 1
    d[team]['total'] += 1
```

Result:

```
print(d)  

{'Team1': {'first': 1, 'second': 2, 'total': 3},
 'Team2': {'first': 1, 'second': 1, 'total': 2}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily invert your flat goals list into a dictionary indexed by the team name and bracket the first and second half immediately so you don't have to do multiple iterations over your data, something like:

```
import collections

team = ((35, 'Team1'), (8, 'Team2'), (55, 'Team1'), (65, 'Team2'), (90, 'Team1'))

team_goals = collections.defaultdict(lambda: [0, 0])  # save some time with a dict factory
for entry in team:
    team_goals[entry[1]][entry[0] > 45] += 1
```

As to how this works - the `collections.defaultdict()` will call the passed factory (`lambda: [0, 0]`) to create a new key whenever a non-existent key is encountered so each team will start with a `[0, 0]` list as its value. Then, as we iterate over the data, all we need is a simple `entry[0] > 45` check as an index selector - [in this context](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-values), it will be treated as an `int` producing `0` for `False` (hence the first half) and `1` for `True` (hence the second half) thus enabling us to select the proper index for increment.

This results with a nice dictionary whose keys are holding the team name while its value is essentially just a two-element list counting the goals in the first and the second half.

If you want to print the data, just use [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to get to your desired table look, something like:

```
line_format = "{:<8} {:^5} {:^6} {:^10}"
print(line_format.format("", "first", "second", "totalgoals"))
for t, g in team_goals.items():
    print(line_format.format(t, g[0], g[1], sum(g)))
```

Which will give you:

```
         first second totalgoals
Team1      1     2        3     
Team2      1     1        2
```

As a bonus, for extra neatness, you can get the biggest string length of the `team_goals` keys and dynamically pad the left-hand side based on your team data.

Comment: Thanks - I haven't confirmed, but I think technically the reason it works is `Boolean` is a subclass of `int` (so no conversion required).

Comment: @jpp - `bool` **is** `int` underneath but Python doesn't strictly prescribe it - it's perfectly possible to create a Python interpreter that has them as separate types. That being said, as per [PEP 285](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0285/), Guido gives a good rationale why it should inherit from `int`. For the sake of clarity, they should be treated as different types, tho - that was the rationale of adding `bool` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok using third party libraries (pandas), which has the distinct advantage of actually displaying a table (which you could export to a variety of formats such as CSV, HTML, etc):

```
In [1]:
df =  pd.DataFrame(list(team), columns=['Value', 'Team'])
df['Goal'] = np.where(df['Value'] <= 45, 'first', 'second')
df = df.groupby('Goal')['Team'].value_counts().unstack(0)
df['totalgoals'] = df.sum(axis=1)
df

Out[1]:
Goal   first  second  totalgoals
Team                            
Team1      1       2           3
Team2      1       1           2
```